# Distributed Marketing Tracking Data in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, distributed-marketing

We are using Distributed Marketing to send emails. But we want tracking to be visible in sales cloud.

Anyone has any idea how to get tracking data in Sales cloud?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also setup MCC https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5 for SFMC to push back IER to SFDC